# trigger parent click event when child is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I'n new to javaScript and jQuery. How is this possible to call the click event of parent element when you click its child?
I have this structure in my code:

```
<ul id="pc5">
   <li><a href="#">book</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want something like this:

```
$("a").click(ul.click);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: in my ul click function I need ul id attribute. something like this:

```
 ul.click(function(e){alert(e.target.id);
```

so when link is clicked, event.target isn't ul element.

Comment: when a child element is clicked the parent's click event also will be fired because of event bubbling unless the event propagation is prevented by the child

Comment: You don't need to do this - the `click` event from the `a` element will bubble to the `ul`, unless you use `return false;` or `event.stopPropagation` on the `a` click handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to trigger element click events when child elements are clicked, the click event `bubbles` up the dom tree if you dont [stop propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Here you can see it working: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJjn6/2/) just click on the blue span, the click event will bubble up to the ul :)

Updated question

If you want the id of the ul, simply to:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
});
```

Which would be even easier like so:

```
$('ul').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   alert(id);
});
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJjn6/3/)**

This should work if you click on an  since it bubbles up

Comment: @Alex: with a few changes my code works perfectly now. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

If your child element is located inside your parent element you could also just add this CSS property.

```
.child {
   pointer-events: none
}
```

This way the click **directly triggers** the parent's click event listener.

This feature's support is [quite good](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer).

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [event propagation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) in jQuery. In few words: when user clicks on `a` then event will be propagated up in DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

I had html like this:

```
<a href="?chk=1">
    <input id="CHK_1" name="CHK[1]" type="checkbox">
    <span>CHK 1</span>
</a>
```

where checkbox was supposed to be checked/unchecked only from server side.
For reason i don't know, 'click' was not bubbling from checkbox to link,
so i used js code like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="CHK_"]', function (e){
    window.open($(this).parent().attr('href'), '_self');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```